# Is su.pr no longer supported?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm looking to shorten permalinks in Wordpress automatically within the loop but it seems there is no information on the su.pr api.

Is su.pr dead?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's alive: see the [su.pr API](http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/su-pr-api/) documentation and there's also a [su.pr WordPress plugin](http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/su-pr-plugin-for-wordpress/).

Answer (score 2):

Per Twitter reply to me this date (11/27/2012) when I inquired (multiple times) why su.pr posts were not making it to Twitter but the URLs were shortened.

I would have to copy the "tweet" into a blank Twitter tweet box before attempting to post it.

Once it failed to post, with a "Retry now >" clickable link, I would copy the shortened URL and replace the long URL with the shortened one in the waiting to be released Twitter tweet box.

Now StumbleUpon's reply:

"@StumbleUponHelp: @katiemae_beader Hi, unfortunately we discontinued su.pr a while back. We will not be fixing issues for su.pr but links should still work."

My response:

@StumbleUponHelp sorry 2 hear that. can't C using su.pr if it doesn't post 2 @Twitter or @Facebook. just makes dbl work 4 me. guess another URL shortener

Now the question that begs to be asked:

How, if at all, does deactivation of su.pr affect StumbleUpon effectiveness?